# QTreeWidget select first branch

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

How can I select the first branch in QTreeWidget/QTreeView?

I need to draw a border over full row, including items and branches. I tried to use QSS code for defining hover style like this:

```
TreeWidget::item:hover {
    border-top: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
}

TreeWidget::item:last:hover {
    border-right: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
}

TreeWidget::branch:hover {
    border-top: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
    border-left: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
}
```

And this works only for items with one branch element:

[image]

But will add extra vertical lines for any sub items:

[image]

How can I draw left border only for the first branch item? Something like this (but this one is not working):

```
TreeWidget::branch:first:hover {
    border-left: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
}
```

UPD1:

I didn't find the way to get first branch from qss, but I found a solution to add only left vertical line. This can be done from `paintEvent`:

```
void TreeWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QTreeWidget::paintEvent(event);

    QPainter painter(viewport());
    auto r = visualItemRect(itemAt(mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos())));
    painter.drawLine(0, r.top(), 0, r.bottom());

}
```